# How to reference a specific instance of an object created by a function? Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, class, object, cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk

Good day all,
I'm pretty confused on how to, for instance, change a property of an object created by a function. By calling the function multiple times I created multiple instances of the same class with the same object name, now I want to change some properties of a single specific object. I guess a little background would be helpful for you folks:
I started to play around in the Cocos2D Chipmunk Engine for the iPhone and in the Example project I can create a character on the screen multiple time by just calling a method. I want to control the forces applied to only one specific character. If you need a more specific example please ask! Thank you =)

Comment: You need to hold a reference to the created object either in an iVar or by an array. I think in cocos2d you can also use a childWithTag: method (or something along that line) to get a child with a specific tag from a scene. (Haven't done much in cocos2d, so not sure about the actual method name)

Comment: Looked it up: it's `getChildByTag:` on `CCNode`

Answer (score 0):

You should create `NSMutableArray` to store your objects:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int i=0; i< 5; i++){
   ........
   // create your object here
   ........
   [myArray addObject:yourObject];
}
```

After that you can access your object by using this:

```
id myObject = [myArray objectAtIndex:1]
```